# Scheduled delivery of messages in IBM MQ

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I am using IBM MQ & active mq in my application using Spring jms. I have a requirement to schedule a message for redelivery after x seconds.

I am able to achieve it in Active mq by setting the AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY header. This makes the message to get delivered to the queue after a specified number of seconds.

Is there anything similar in IBM MQ that I can use to achieve the above mentioned functionality ?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Well JMS 1.1 specification does not mention anything about delayed delivery of a message. Hence you don't have that feature in WMQ. Just released JMS 2.0 specification describes this feature.

Answer (score 0):

yeah, WMQ isn't the best JMS impl for that sort of thing. Take a look at apache camel. It can provide this sort of delayed message routing.